# how can i output the six numbers in an array because it is giving me only zero

Tags: arrays, vb.net

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Num1 As Byte
    Dim Num2 As Byte
    Dim Num3 As Byte
    Dim Num4 As Byte
    Dim Num5 As Byte
    Dim Num6 As Byte
    Dim arrValue(5) As Integer
    Dim result As String = String.Join("", arrValue)

    Randomize()
    Num1 = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 40))
    Console.WriteLine("Num1:" & Num1)
    arrValue(0) = Num1

    Randomize()
    Num2 = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 40))
    arrValue(1) = Num2
    Console.WriteLine("Num2:" & Num2)

    Randomize()
    Num3 = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 40))
    Console.WriteLine("Num3:" & Num3)
    arrValue(2) = Num3


    Randomize()
    Num4 = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 40))
    Console.WriteLine("Num4:" & Num4)
    arrValue(3) = Num4

    Randomize(Num5)
    Num5 = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 40))
    Console.WriteLine("Num5:" & Num5)
    arrValue(4) = Num5

    Randomize()
    Num6 = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 40))
    Console.WriteLine("Num6:" & Num6)
    arrValue(5) = Num6

    Console.WriteLine("" & result)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be nice if you tell anyone what's the language you are using here

Comment: It's unnecessary to call Randomize() before each call to Rnd()

Comment: Why are you not outputting arrValue at any point, given your question?

Comment: This code suffers from redundancy in a way that makes it look *very* amateurish, maybe OP could use a beginner's tutorial. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_code

Comment: Please be more clear on what you are asking. Also, please look at vb array syntax before asking stackoverflow...

Answer (score 1):

Carefully check the timeline in your code:

- when do you assign the contents to `result`?
- when do you assign the values to the array?

Hint: This code is executed from top to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim result As String = String.Join("", arrValue)
```

should be moved to before

```
Console.WriteLine("" & result)
```

becoming

```
Dim result As String
...
result = String.Join("", arrValue)
Console.WriteLine("" & result)
```

because you're creating the string from the values before you've created values for them.

Comment: thank you very much Josh your help was very much apperciated.now everything is working properly